# The minimal polynomial of a vector is a factor of the minimal polynomial of a linear transform

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

Let $V$ be a linear space on field $P$, $\mathcal A$ is a linear transformation on $V$, and $\xi$ is a vector in $V$.

The minimal polynomial of $\xi$ about $\mathcal A$ is the polynomial with the lowest exponent and satisfying $f(\mathcal A)\xi = 0$.

I am new in algebra and what confuse me are:

(i) How to show that the minimal polynomial (about $\mathcal A)$ of each vector is a factor of the minimal polynomial of $\mathcal A$.

(ii) For a given set of basis, how to show that the least common multiple of the minimal polynomials of each basis vector is the minimal polynomial of $\mathcal A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(i) Suppose $p$ is the minimal polynomial for $\xi$. Let $m$ be another polynomial such that $m(A)\xi=0$, for example the minimal polynomial of $A$. Then dividing $m$ by $p$, $$ m=qp+r$$ $$r(A)\xi=m(A)\xi-q(A)p(A)\xi=0$$ Since $p$ is the minimal polynomial it follows that $r=0$ and $p$ is a factor of $m$.

(ii) Let $m$ be the lcm of $p_i$, which are the min polys of the basis vectors $e_i$. Then for any vector $\xi=\sum_i\alpha_ie_i$ $$m(A)\xi=\sum_i\alpha_im(A)e_i=0$$ since $m(A)e_i=q_i(A)p_i(A)e_i=0$. This means that $m(A)=0$. Secondly, suppose $p$ is some polynomial such that $p(A)=0$. Then each $p_i$ divides $p$ by part (i), and so their lcm $m$ does too. These two parts, that $m(A)=0$ and that $m$ divides any other polynomial $p(A)=0$ is the definition of minimal polynomial of $A$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Chrystomath

Comment: @PumpKin You're welcome! Accept?

Comment: Sure! Clearly! @Chrystomath

Comment: @PumpKin There's the Accept button on the left side if you're happy with the answer.